# how can i access the textbox inside the datagrid using the events of that datagrid?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a textbox in a datagrid that is designed using xaml. Can I access the textbox which has been designed in xaml previously in codefile using the events of the datagrid. Please help me.....................

```
      <Window x:Class="GridTextBox.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" WindowState="Maximized"
    Title="Test" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>

        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Name="datagrid1" SelectionChanged="datagrid1_SelectionChanged" LoadingRowDetails="DataGrid_LoadingRowDetails"  Height="auto" Width="auto">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Name="txtEmpid" Text="hiiiiii"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: how to access textbox txtEmpid using the events of datagrid1?????? Please help me

Comment: with event what you mean??? key down in text box and you want to handle it as data grid key down? you can look for Routed Events

Comment: whenever user clicks on the grid ... i.e. through selected index changed event I want to get the text in the textbox as hiiiii

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to get use `ItemContainerGenerator` to get the correct row from data (in your datagrid1_SelectionChanged event).

```
var row = (DataGridRow)datagrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.
                     ContainerFromItem(datagrid1.SelectedItem);
```

then get the TextBlock like this:

```
var text = datagrid1.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
```

Comment: I can't get this to work - I got the correct row, `GetCellContent` returned a `ContentPresenter` which, after "as" casting to TextBox, becomes `null`. My XAML looks very close to the one in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cellInfo=dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0];
var txt=cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
```

or there is one more solution to get the text for all text box where there are dynamic rows are there.

```
 DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;

int Columnindex = datagrid1.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
 int iGridRowsCount      = ArgumentsDataGridforTestcasessTab.Items.Count;
for (int jRow = 0; jRow <= iGridRowsCount - 1; jRow++)
{

  DataGridCell cell = GetCell(jRow, Columnindex);
  ContentPresenter _contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter();
  _contentPresenter = (ContentPresenter)cell.Content;

  // get the attached control from the cell
  TextBox myTextBox = GetVisualChild<TextBox>(_contentPresenter);                 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention whether the cell is in edit mode, or only in preview mode. If it is in edit mode (I mean you are writing into it, or you just wrote something and did not move to other cell) it won't cast to TextBlock, but to a Textbox.

When (only) it is in preview mode, it will cast to TextBlock, indeed.

I ran in the same issue and I resolved it with a try-catch sequence upon the casting the content to Textbox.

Did something like

```
try
{
   var myTextboxVariable=(Textbox) datagridcell.Content
   //extract the text out of myVariable.Text, do whatever you intend to the Textbox
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  var myTextBlockVariable=(TextBlock) datagridcell.Content
  //extract the text out of myVariable.Text, do whatever you intend to the TextBlock
}
```

I know it looks like a brute solution, and there must be a more elegant way. But in the end it is the outcome that matters. Time is a coordinate in our dimension :)